# Bootstrap Hover Link Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made this demo page with Bootstrap. No matter how I change the styles, it will not allow me to make the links situated on the right change color on hover.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Link to page: http://coffeesite.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com

Comment: Please create a fiddle, read the [ask] page and come back with a small, reproduceable sample of your code. THEN, we can start debugging your issue (linking to an external site is not recommended practice since the moment the site disappears, the question is no longer self-contained and/or useful to others)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened dev tools and changed the default li > a background color to red, and your background color was successfully changing to transparent on hover and active (after click).

```
.masthead-nav > li > a:hover,
.masthead-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;

}
```

You're not seeing any change because you're not setting an initial background color.  Just add something like

```
.masthead-nav > li > a {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* or you know.. whatever color you want */
}
```